# laravel 5.3 does not seem to update instantly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i haven't had this problem using slim or anything else before.

When I do a change in my IDE, and then reload the page, the change is not always instantly visible. That is, i have to wait a couple seconds, then try again.

How comes? is there a way i get force this process quicker?

Comment: Did you upload files through ssh to your server or use mounted disk?

Comment: it is local development. That is when i press save, intellij-idea will deploy the files to a local folder. That is locally it puts them into `/var/www/html/mylaravelapp/...`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe it's this:

in intellij-idea there is an option "preserve timestamp" in settings - deployment - options. Maybe that fools laravel into thinking the files didn't actually change